# how to export cassandra db into another system?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using a Cassandra database with several key-spaces. Now i want to use that key-spaces within another system.

What are valid options to achieve that?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cqlsh COPY` command to export your data into csv. Then you can import csv into your other database if it is supported, e.g.:

`COPY keyspace.tablename (column1, column2, ..) TO '../export.csv' WITH HEADER = TRUE ;`

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html